# How can I add tab on lightning

Tags: apex, visualforce, administration, admin

I want add tab on lightning toggle bar. I have created lightning component tab and added in Salesforce1 navigation menu. But it is not showing when I switch to Salesforce lightning. It showing when I login only in mobile. Is there any possibility to add tab.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go thru the [Spring 16 release notes](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_forcecom_general_lex_navigation_menus_create.htm) , you will find the instructions on how to customize the lightning navigation menu.

From the Quick Setup, search for Navigation and you will find the option to add your lightning component tab to the navigation.

Note : the Salesforce 1 Navigation and Lightning Experience Navigation are different.

[image]